# Why is this for loop with an unsigned int endless?

Tags: c, for-loop, infinite-loop, unsigned, unsigned-integer

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (i == 2) i = -1;
}
```

I can't understand why this loop is infinite. I get that it wraps around when `i = -1` but UINT_MAX is greater than 3.

Comment: Yes -1 is UINT_MAX and then i++ happens so i becames 0 again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I rewrite your code, then might more clear to see why

```
unsigned i = 0;
while (i < 3) {
    if (i == 2) i = -1;
    i++;
}
```

`i++` happens at the end of the loop so `i` became `0` again.

Answer (score 1):

because once `i` become `2` it will change to `0` then with `i++`,
loop continue until `i=2` again and so it change to `0` again and same process will go on.

Answer (score 1):

If you want that in the condition of the loop

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (i == 2) i = -1;
}
```

there were compared `UINT_MAX` with `3` you should write

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (i == 2) i = -2;
}
```

In this case incrementing `i` you will get `UINT_MAX`. Otherwise if `i` already contains `UINT_MAX` then incrementing it in the loop expression `i++` you will get 0 and as a result an infinite loop.

Or you could write for example the following way

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (i == 2) i = ~i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because for loop will be executed according to this arrangement

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 3; i++)
```

1>>initial value  (i=0) at the first iteration only
2>>check the terminal condition

```
(i<3)
```

3>>execute the code

```
(if(i==2) i=-1)
```

4>>incremental step i++ so (i always became zero) as (-1+1=0)
so this loop is infinite loop

Comment: "_(i always became zero) as (-1+1=0)_" -- yet `-1 + 1` is nowhere to be found. `i` is `unsigned int`, so `i = -1` sets `i` to `UINT_MAX` (which must be _at least_ 65535). The subsequent `i++` attempts to increment `i` beyond `UINT_MAX`, causing unsigned wrap-around to 0. The effect is the same, but the details are wrong.